# Understanding Conformal Equivalences

Tags: geometry, conformal-geometry

In the book "Computational Conformal Geometry" by David Gu, the author writes:

*"Riemann uniformization theorem states that all surfaces in real life can be conformally mapped to one of three canonical shapes: the unit sphere, the Euclidean plane, and
the hyperbolic space."*

The the following section he says:

*"Surfaces can be classified using conformal geometry. Two surfaces are conformally
equivalent if they can be conformally mapped to each other."*

Now, what I understand from these sentences would be that, since every surface in 3D can be conformally mapped to either a sphere, a plane or a disc, then these would be the only equivalence classes for conformal equivalence in 3D... This does not seems correct. What am I misunderstanding from these statements?

Comment: Yes, the claim in the book is simply false.

Comment: It’s the reverse. Given any surface in Euclidean 3-space, there exists a conformal covering map from the standard sphere, the flat plane, or the flat disk onto the surface.